# How to set different output in Sequential Tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Sequential Tasks returns same output even lock the output. Even no clouser variables.
For example

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew((arg) =>
      {
          int taskid = (int)i;
          IteratingFunction(taskid);
      }, i);
    tasks.Add(t);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

And the method is

```
public void IteratingFunction(int s)
{
    lock (Console.Out)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running task is: {0}",s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the modified closure, try capture the value of x outside of the lambda function:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // capture taskid here
    int taskid = (int)i;
    Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew((arg) =>
    {
        IteratingFunction(taskid);
    }, i);
    tasks.Add(t);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```